# Why isn't an order type used for comparisons in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml, sml

I have yet to find a suitable answer for an OCaml design decision, and hope one of those here with in-depth knowledge of OCaml's implementation can shed some light.

In SML, if we evaluate `Int.compare(6, 9)` we get `LESS` which is a constructor for the `order` type (the others being `GREATER` and `EQUAL`). In OCaml, if we evaluate `compare 6 9` we get `-1`.

Was there a specific reason to favor having comparison functions return zero, a negative number, or a positive number in OCaml's standard library, rather than an algebraic data type as in SML?

Comment: My guess is because it's easy and efficient. If the values are integers, or can easily be reduced to integers (such as ´char`s and variant constructors), the comparison is a simple subtraction.

Comment: It's most likely "for historical reasons", and I think you would need ask the developers of the original Caml system why that particular decision was made. (I wouldn't be surprised if the answer were "it was natural because of C", though.)

Comment: For what it's worth, SML is not alone in having an ADT for this. Haskell has an `Ordering` type as well, and while Scala uses `Int` for compatibility with Java, the Scalaz library defines its own `Ordering` type as well.

Comment: Maybe because it's actually easy to manipulate integers. If you want the opposite comparison, you can simply negate it. If you wanted to implement comparison between two numbers, you can literally just subtract them (and a lot of things may turn out to be numbers, as @glennsl said). You could even multiply two comparisons, to get a new one. That doesn't sound very useful on its own, but if you day you need that specific comparison, think about how more easy it is than if it was a regular enum.

Comment: “you can literally just subtract them” Except you have 50% chance of getting it in the wrong direction. Personally, I check the manual every time. By contrast, a comparison datatype like `Lt | Eq | Gt` is declarative and if the stdlib used that, it would provide functions for negating or combining comparisons, so that’s just as easy as using integer operations.

Comment: @BlackBeans: OCaml's `int` type provides fixed-width two's-complement integers, and the return-value of `compare` can be any `int`, so unless I'm missing something, negation and multiplication can both give bad/inconsistent results due to integer overflow.

Comment: @Maëlan actually, I see it the other way around. When I see `compare x y = Lt`, I have no mnemonic way to know which of `x` or `y` is actually the smallest (and I mean when I do that in other languages that have ADT). Instead, I just have to remember, in OCaml, that `compare = (-)`. That way, I know that `compare x y = -X` is roughly `x - y ≈ -X`, that is, `x` is less than `y`. But I'm not advocating for `compare` to work like that: I personally prefer how it works in other languages, with ADTs.

Comment: The argument that `compare` for ints is just `-` does not seem to be supported by `compare 100 1` yielding `1` rather than `99`. It would seem at least one more step is being performed. While `compare` is specified to return `0`, a negative integer, or a positive integer, I have never seen the standard library ever return anything other than `0`, `-1`, or `1`.

Comment: @BlackBeans  the mnemonic for `compare x y = Lt` is: replace "compare" by the value: `Lt x y`, `Gt x y` or `Eq x y`, just like `(<) 3 7` is true